# How to open ports on could VPS on google? No matter what I try all the ports are closed

Tags: google-compute-engine

How to open port on could VPS on google? No matter what I try all the ports are closed

i try ingress and egree rule

action : allow
source filter: 0.0.0.0/0
protocols and ports: all
priority : 65535

despite my best efforts all ports i check are shown as closed https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Comment: What is the `Targets` selection for the VPC Firewall rule? Which OS? Is there an OS firewall running? Edit your post with more details. The firewall rule in your post is risky. Only allow specific ports and/or specific IP addresses.